# Get-AzurePublishSettingsFile gives Class not registered error

Tags: powershell, azure

I installed the Azure Powershell Command lets (from here https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/downloads)

I also ran the

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
```

I then run the Windows Azure PowerShell under administrator credentials

However I get the following error

```
Get-AzurePublishSettingsFile : Class not registered
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-AzurePublishSettingsFile
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Get-AzurePublishSettingsFile],  Win32Exception
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Cmdlets.GetAzurePublishSettingsCommand
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the private key of (or on) the certificate in order for this to work correctly.  I found this out after a lot of trail and error.

But in short if your certificate manager does not have a little key icon over the certificate (the second certificate in the screen shot), it means you don't have a private key, and that means that Powershell will not be able to connect to Azure.

[image]

I noted down the things that I learned over here:

[Management certificates and powershell deployment to windows azure](http://frameworkone.wordpress.com/2012/09/10/management-certificates-and-powershell-deployment-to-windows-azure/)

Answer (score 5):

I had exactly the same problem on Windows 8 while using Chrome as my default browser.

The solution is to have **`Internet Explorer`** be the default program for opening browser related files like `*.html`.

```
Internet Explorer > Internet Settings > Programs > Set associations = Select all
```

This does the trick. Maybe a single entry would suffice but I didn't check that.

Answer (score 2):

Check to see what the value is in `$pshome`

If you see `%windir%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0` you are running [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) in 32bit mode. **This is the version of PowerShell you will want to use for the Windows Azure PowerShell Cmdlets.**

If you see `%windir%\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0` you are running in x64 mode, which may cause issues.

Comment: It is running under the 32bit version ($PSHOME = C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0) 
I am running windows 8 RTM anything else that I can check?

Answer (score 1):

Also, ensure you are NOT running powershell 'As Administrator'

Answer (score 0):

I use a non-administrator account to open powershell then it worked.

Notice launching the command would open up a web page at this [url](https://manage.windowsazure.com/publishsettings/index?client=powershell) to download the publish settings file for your Azure account.

So effectively, you may open the link above without using the command.

Hope this helps.